# linking error when trying to assign cout to ostream variable

Tags: visual-c++

I encount follow linker error

> unresolved extrenal symbol "class std::basic_ostream > std::cout"
>   (?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A)"

when trying to assign std::cout to static constexpr std::stream when using visual stidio 2017 and visual studio 2019. No problem, however, encounters when using gcc.

Following simple testing code could indicate this problem

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    static constexpr std::ostream* fp = &std::cout;
    *fp << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Both expression of

```
constexpr std::ostream* fp = &std::cout;
```

or

```
static std::ostream* fp = &std::cout;
```

are confirmed to be OK.

My question is:

Is

```
static constexpr std::ostream* fp = &std::cout;
```

a legitimate expression. If not, why?

Much thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @KenWhite. I cannot find solution from your link. Tanks anyway